# Fast alternative to run a numpy based function over all the rows in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, cython

I have a Pandas data frame created the following way:

```
import pandas as pd
def create(n):  
    df = pd.DataFrame({ 'gene':["foo",
                            "bar",
                            "qux",
                            "woz"], 
                            'cell1':[433.96,735.62,483.42,10.33], 
                            'cell2':[94.93,2214.38,97.93,1205.30],
                            'cell3':[1500,90,100,80]})
    df = df[["gene","cell1","cell2","cell3"]]
    df = pd.concat([df]*n)
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
    return df
```

It looks like this:

```
In [108]: create(1)
Out[108]:
  gene   cell1    cell2  cell3
0  foo  433.96    94.93   1500
1  bar  735.62  2214.38     90
2  qux  483.42    97.93    100
3  woz   10.33  1205.30     80
```

Then I have a function that takes the values of each genes(row)
to compute a certain score:

[image]

```
import numpy as np 
def sparseness(xvec):
    n = len(xvec)
    xvec_sum = np.sum(np.abs(xvec))
    xvecsq_sum = np.sum(np.square(xvec))

    denom = np.sqrt(n) - (xvec_sum / np.sqrt(xvecsq_sum))
    enum  = np.sqrt(n) - 1
    sparseness_x = denom/enum

    return sparseness_x
```

In reality I need to apply this function on 40K over rows. And currently it runs
very slow using Pandas 'apply':

```
In [109]: df = create(10000)
In [110]: express_df   = df.ix[:,1:]
In [111]: %timeit express_df.apply(sparseness, axis=1)
1 loops, best of 3: 8.32 s per loop
```

What's the faster alternative to implement that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A faster way is to implement a vectorized version of the function, which operates on a two dimensional ndarray directly. This is very doable since many functions in numpy can operate on two dimensional ndarray, controlled using the `axis` parameter. A possible implementation:

```
def sparseness2(xs):
    nr = np.sqrt(xs.shape[1])
    a = np.sum(np.abs(xs), axis=1)
    b = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(xs), axis=1))
    sparseness = (nr - a/b) / (nr - 1)
    return sparseness

res_arr = sparseness2(express_df.values)
res2 = pd.Series(res_arr, index=express_df.index)
```

Some testing:

```
from pandas.util.testing import assert_series_equal
res1 = express_df.apply(sparseness, axis=1)
assert_series_equal(res1, res2) #OK
%timeit sparseness2(express_df.values)
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 655 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's one vectorized approach using [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) to perform all those operations in one go across the entire dataframe. Now, this `np.einsum` is supposedly pretty efficient for such multiplication and summing purposes. In our case, we can use it to perform summation along one dimension for the `xvec_sum` case and squaring and summation for the `xvecsq_sum` case. The implmentation would look like this -

```
def sparseness_vectorized(A):
    nsqrt = np.sqrt(A.shape[1])
    B = np.einsum('ij->i',np.abs(A))/np.sqrt(np.einsum('ij,ij->i',A,A))    
    denom = nsqrt - B
    enum  = nsqrt - 1
    return denom/enum
```

---

Runtime tests -

This section compares all the approaches listed thus far to solve the problem including the one in the question.

```
In [235]: df = create(1000)
     ...: express_df  = df.ix[:,1:]
     ...: 

In [236]: %timeit express_df.apply(sparseness, axis=1)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.36 s per loop

In [237]: %timeit sparseness2(express_df.values)
1000 loops, best of 3: 247 µs per loop

In [238]: %timeit sparseness_vectorized(express_df.values)
1000 loops, best of 3: 231 µs per loop



In [239]: df = create(5000)
     ...: express_df  = df.ix[:,1:]
     ...: 

In [240]: %timeit express_df.apply(sparseness, axis=1)
1 loops, best of 3: 6.66 s per loop

In [241]: %timeit sparseness2(express_df.values)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.14 ms per loop

In [242]: %timeit sparseness_vectorized(express_df.values)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.06 ms per loop
```